# change default navigation keys in arnold cpc emulator without recompiling?

Tags: key, emulation, configure

In the arnold cpc emulator, the default navigation arrow keys (up, down, left, right) are Q, A, O and P. Is there a way to map these to the conventional arrow keys without recompiling from source? A config file maybe?

Some games do not have a "reconfigure keys" facility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WinAPE](http://www.winape.net/) comes to the rescue... You can set the navigation arrows from the input settings section...